# Blender Best Car Crash Problem

Tags: animation, modifiers, rigging, bones, physics

I have been trying to find the best car crash with the following conditions:

1. Rotating wheels when car is accelerating
2. Car skidding, thus front wheels turn left or right (image the driver trying to take but control of the vehicle and end up drifting)
3. Car hit an obstacle on the road at high speed and fly off course
4. Car Crashing (glass shattered, metal part tented)

I have looked through plenty of tutorials on Youtube. How, I am unable to find one tutorial that fulfill all the above conditions.

If I use bones to rig a car, does it mean that there is no possibility for parts of the car to fly off? example the door or a wheel.

--> How can I dent the metal parts? Which modifier should I use?

On Youtube, there are these 2 channels Albin MERLE and TopChannel1on1. Their method require creating a mesh to wrap around the main part of the car and 4 separate cylinder mesh for the wheels.
---> What are the constraints using this method? What are the things I can't do?

I am trying out using this beautiful Mercedes (https://free3d.com/3d-model/mercedes-amg-c63-hi-poly-model-partially-rigged-805791.html). Credits to wishingchain. Whenever I try to add a rigid body onto part of the car, the part will just fall off.
---> What is the reason for that?

This is my first post here. I've tried all avenues and can't seem to find a solution. Will any kind soul please help?

I look forward to a Youtube tutorial on this topic in the near future.

Thank you.

John

Comment: Thats a pretty complex topic. Just answering some question because other way it would be too long. I have done it and its hard and you have to be organized. Look into rigid body contraints when you want something to fly off during the animation. You can dent the metal with a second mesh wrapped around your car and using a soft body on the mesh. You can then bind it to the real car with a mesh deform modifier. Your car is falling apart because and thats only a guess its not one object and the rigid body sim is on every part separately.

Comment: Hi. I appreciate you have a complex problem and have found a solution to part of it, but this is a Q and A site is for *specific* questions that can have *specific* answers. The fact that you have a 4 part answer probably shows this question is too broad at the minute. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask multiple questions but as separate posts. I suggest editing your question down to just one question (by using the [edit] link below it) and asking the other ones separately. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After a day of research, I found out some of the answers and I am going to answer to my own questions

1. Rotating wheels when car is accelerating <- for the wheels, add drivers to an empty axis, then move the axis, the wheels should rotate (tested out, it works)
2. Car skidding, thus front wheels turn left or right (imagine the driver trying to take but control of the vehicle and end up drifting) <- rotate the front wheels on the z-axis via the empty axis in between key frames (haven't test it out, still figuring out how to add drivers on the z-axis)
3. Car hit an obstacle on the road at high speed and fly off course <- parent the empty axis to a cube, the cube is in the shape of the car, wrapping around the car (tested out. tried hitting the cube together with the car to a stationary pole straight on. not sure why, but upon impact, the pole was absorbed into the cube and car and stayed inside them. the cube and car then kept shaking while the pole is inside of them)
4. Car Crashing (glass shattered, metal part tented) <- upon impact, manually dent the car and use key shape key function. not sure about shattered glass. perhaps separate the glass parts from the car at the key frame upon impact? I know about cell fracture but not unsure how to make the glass break upon impact. the windscreens are tempered glass, depending on impact, it should either crack or break. (tested out only on denting the car, it works)

It seems like there's no way to add a rigid body onto the car. That is why I have to parent the car to the cube (that is in the shape of the car). Because every time I add a rigid body to the car, those parts that have a rigid body added will just drop onto the ground all over the place. Please let me know if there's a way around it.

Hope someone will be able to help, especially with the cracking of tempered glass and glass shattering part. Windscreen should crack while side and rear windows should shatter. Because every time I try to add a rigid body to the car, everything just fall apart. I will update again if I can find out more.

Have fun crashing.

John

Comment: There is also a quick explode effect you add to the glass. Just select the glass, press the Object menu on the top bar and press quick effects then quick explode.