# How to copy key frames to multiple cell fractured objects while object stays in original position

Tags: animation, modifiers, objects, vertex-groups

Previously, I wrote on "Blender Best Car Crash Problem".
[Blender Best Car Crash Problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182228/blender-best-car-crash-problem).

I posted quite a few questions there. The thread has been closed. This is the first time using such forum. I will try to be as detailed as possible. Please bear with me.

Thank you Schamph, Ray Mairlot and Eric Xue for the replies.

This problem is with regards to glass shattering.

I think I figured out how to shatter part of the glass upon impact, leaving part of the circumference of the glass attached to the window frames and the frame of the windshield.

I added a flat shape that I want to shatter (can be a plane or circle, or modify it yourself) that is smaller than the glass. I then added a modifier to shrink wrap the shape to the glass as I do not want any part of the glass to be protruding out. (Actually if both the glass and shape are completely flat and flushed, shrink wrap is not necessary.) Next, I clicked on the shape, and then click on the glass, and Ctrl+P set to parent object. I selected "object (keep transform)". I then added the cell fracture quick effect to the glass and selected "Child Verts". Following that, I selected the circumference of the glass to be shattered and joined them to the glass frame (or the main body of the car) so they will not move upon impact, leaving only those un-joined parts to fly out. I shall not touch too much on rigid body settings but remember to check "deactivation", expand that and also check "start deactivated" so the glass will only shatter upon impact.

My question now is this. Under rigid body, one frame before the crash, I need to select each glass fragment (that will be shattered) one at a time, with "animated" box checked, move the mouse cursor a bit to the right, and then click on “animate property” to add a key frame. Then move to the next frame (this is when the crash happen), un-check "animated" and insert another time frame by clicking the “animate property” again. I can do a CTRL + L to copy “animated data”. However, all the fragments will be clustered together as the location will be copied too.

Is there a way to just leave the location untouched and just copy the “animate property” part?

Thank you.

John

Update on June 15, 2020, 2:15am ET:
I think I found the solution.
Before adding any key frames, parent all the fragments and all parts of the car (wheels, body, head lights etc.) to the same "empty axis".
In doing so, animation data can be copied for multiple objects all at once without displacing the location. Without the "empty axis", all the glass fragments will be clustered into the same location after animation data is copied over. When positioning the car to a particular key frame, I don't just select the "empty axis", I selected everything that is linked to the car (glass fragments, body, wheels, headlights, etc.) including the "empty axis". The wheels will still rotate from frame to frame if you have already added drivers to them.

Comment: Did you try pressing ALT when clicking the checkbox? That should change that property on all selected objects.

Comment: Hi Samir, Thank you for the reply. I pressed CTRL + L and selected animation data instead. I am able to copy. However, the problem now is that this function copies the location too. So I end up having glass fragments all clustered in one location. Is there a way around it by not copying the location?

Comment: ***Did you try pressing ALT when clicking the checkbox?*** (I'm assuming the answer is no, but please help people out, when they ask for clarification.)

Comment: Hi Leander and Samir, sorry for not clarifying. Yes, I did. I selected everything, then press ALT and clicked on the animation check box, that did not work. I also tried ALT and clicked on the animate property. That did not work either. Not sure if I am doing it incorrectly.

Not sure if I phrase my question correctly. What I want to do is to add a key frame by clicking on the animate property (the small round button beside the checkbox). And I want to do it for multiple pieces of the glass fragments all at once.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try copy from active in the rigid body menu from the top menu in the viewport?

Comment: Hi EANIIX, Thank you for the reply. Yes, I copy from active in the rigid body menu from the top menu in the view port. But it did not work. I appreciate your help